# NSPredicate through nested array using the dictionary key

Tags: ios, xcode, nspredicate

Could someone help me how to predicate through the below data and retrieve the value for the key "Text". Initially i have dictionary with the below data

```
{
    ArrayName1 =     (
                {
            Target = "<null>";
            Text = "Name1";
            Value = 1;
        },
                {
            Target = "<null>";
            Text = "Name2";
            Value = 2;
        }
    );
    ArrayName2 =     (
                {
            Target = "<null>";
            Text = "Name3";
            Value = 3;
        },
                {
            Target = "<null>";
            Text = "Name4";
            Value = 4;
        }
    );
    ArrayName3 =     (
                {
            Target = "<null>";
            Text = "Name5";
            Value = 5;
        },
                {
            Target = "<null>";
            Text = "Name6";
            Value = 6;
        }
    );
    ArrayName4 =     (
                {
            Target = "<null>";
            Text = "somename";
            Value = somevalue;
        }
    );
    ArrayName4 =     (
                {
            Target = "<null>";
            Text = "somename";
            Value = "somevalue";
        }
    );
}
```

I want the end result to be stored in the "resultarray" which should contain value of "Text" key by the search string from all the array and also want to store the corresponding value for the "Value" key in the same array.

Thanks,
Pradeep

Comment: Show what you have tried it before ? and can you please post example what you want at the end of search ?

Comment: post the code you have tried so far..?

Comment: @Dev.RK, please check below  the methods i tried.

Answer (score 0):

@Dev.RK @Cyph3r - Below are the methods i tried. @Dev.RK,@Cyph3r. I tried the below methods including compound predicate.

```
//Method 1
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K.%K CONTAINS[c] %@", @"Practice",@"Text",searchTextString];
searchArray = [[quickSearchDataDict allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];


//Method 2
NSPredicate *predicateArray1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(TEXT==%@)",searchTextString];
  NSPredicate * predicateArray2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.%K.%K contains[c] %@",@"ArrayName2",@"Text",searchTextString];
     NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicateArray1,predicateArray2]];
searchArray = [[quickSearchDataDict allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this will solved your problem-

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *ary=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dic setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"none"] forKey:@"Target"];
        [dic setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tst%d",j] forKey:@"Text"];
        [dic setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j+i] forKey:@"Value"];
        [ary addObject:dic];
    }
    [dict setObject:ary forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ArrayName%d",i]];
}

NSArray *searchary=[dict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"ArrayName0"]];

NSPredicate *pre0 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.%K contains[cd] %@",@"Text", @"tst"];

NSArray *resultArray=  [searchary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pre0];

NSLog(@"%@",resultArray);
```

here is the log-

**1. Text==tst0**

```
(
        {
        Target = none;
        Text = tst0;
        Value = 0;
    }
)
```

**2. Text==tst**

```
(
        {
        Target = none;
        Text = tst0;
        Value = 0;
    },
        {
        Target = none;
        Text = tst1;
        Value = 1;
    }
)
```

and this is complete data-

```
{
    ArrayName0 =     (
                {
            Target = none;
            Text = tst0;
            Value = 0;
        },
                {
            Target = none;
            Text = tst1;
            Value = 1;
        }
    );
    ArrayName1 =     (
                {
            Target = none;
            Text = tst0;
            Value = 1;
        },
                {
            Target = none;
            Text = tst1;
            Value = 2;
        }
    );
    ArrayName2 =     (
                {
            Target = none;
            Text = tst0;
            Value = 2;
        },
                {
            Target = none;
            Text = tst1;
            Value = 3;
        }
    );
    ArrayName3 =     (
                {
            Target = none;
            Text = tst0;
            Value = 3;
        },
                {
            Target = none;
            Text = tst1;
            Value = 4;
        }
    );
    ArrayName4 =     (
                {
            Target = none;
            Text = tst0;
            Value = 4;
        },
                {
            Target = none;
            Text = tst1;
            Value = 5;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. I was able to segregate the dictionary into multiple array and predicate through each array. But i want the predicate to be done for all the arrays and combine the matching string's key value pair to be in one array.

Comment: means you don't want particular array to predicate i.e. ArrayName0?

Comment: I want all the arrays in the 'dict' to be predicated and the matching should be in one array. I did some alternate , combined all the arrays (ArrayName1, ArrayName2,etc) into one array and predicating it. Nevertheless , let me know if you find solution for my intention.